# rendering word documents on mobile devices

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, web, ms-word

We are creating a mobile site that will allow the user access to download word documents.

We have a website for non-mobile devices that allows access but what is the best way of doing this from mobile that can reach as many devices.

Would we be better using pdfs for the website or how can we guarantee that the user-agent will be able to display a downloaded word document?

Comment: How can you guarantee it can display PDFs?  Or any other file?  HTML is probably the closest to a common denominator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php to get the contents from the file and display it in html.

```
<?php
$doc = file_get_contents('something.txt'); 
echo $doc; 
?>
```

That would display something like

> test document

Some phones wont be able to download and view the files, so displaying them on the page will make it easier.